# Magento Get url after the main url

Tags: magento, php

I have looked all over the internet, but can not find the following answer:

We want to get the part in Magento in .phtml after the main url so if:

domain.com/shoes.html we want to get only shoes.html

This is important because we have a multishop in .nl and .be and we want to use the hreflang. We need to give in both shops the url of both shops so as well from the .be and the .nl and then with the subcategory or product url.

In .phtml you can get the current url with: helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>

With that code you will get the total url so domain.com/shoes.html and we only want the part shoes.html

Would be great if someone knows the answer

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 25):

You could do this:

```
$urlString = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($urlString);
$path = $url->getPath();
```

$path will contain the URL excluding the domain name.

Comment: Works! I also used this to get "mysite.com" with `$url->getHost()`

Comment: @JamesHalsall, By `this`, I'm guessing you mean Magento. I came here because [EQP](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp) doesn't want me using `basename()`. Bah

Comment: @aross yeah I mean Magento :)

Answer (score 8):

You can get that filename by using PHP's basename method

```
$url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); //http://domain.com/shoes.html
echo basename($url); //outputs shoes.html
```

Comment: I tried this option but did not get it to work. What I want to do is get the part after the main url so shoes.html to fit behind two urls and only in code. We want to get it behind a hreflang: we have a dutch and belgium site so .nl and .be in bot headers we want to have the ur .nl and .be with the extention behind it so: .be/shoes.html and .nl/shoes.html. How would this work, we tried href="domain.nl/<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" but then you get domain.nl/domain.nl and we want to get domain.nl/shoes.html?

Answer (score 4):

I had two problems with some of the suggestions here, firstly getBaseUrl() included the port number, and secondly my base URL includes a store directory, e.g. www.example.com/store (which is included in getBaseUrl() and the RightThing). The answer was to look at the code for getCurrentUrl() and create my own current URL that didn't hide the port.

The following code worked for me:

```
<?php
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$port = ':' . $request->getServer('SERVER_PORT');

$currentUrl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $port . $request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');

$relUrl = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '', $currentUrl);
    echo '<p>Base: ' .  Mage::getBaseUrl() . '</p>';
    echo '<p>This: ' . $currentUrl . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Repl: ' . $relUrl . '</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get what you're asking for, it just depends exactly what you want. You could get the current url as you're doing and remove the base url (`Mage::getBaseUrl()`) with a `str_replace`.

Or, you could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Dear Nachito, I place above a explanation of what we try to do, can you take a look if you know how we have to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()
```

or

```
$currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
```

above code may not work always as expected. Better way to find the current url is to use the following code:

```
if (!in_array(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName(), array('cms_index_noRoute', 'cms_index_defaultNoRoute'))) {
    $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
}
```

Comment: why may not work the following url ?? **$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()** or **$currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));**